# Using MSbuild to publish a webproject through command line

Tags: visual-studio, web-applications, command-line, msbuild, publish

I am trying to publish webproject but it is not creating the Script and views folder in the destination directory through the following command but when published through Visual studio it is creating all needed files and directories 
I gave the following command.

`msbuild Y:\system\WebApp.csproj/p:Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile=WebApp;outdir="C:\Users\Desktop\Temp";VisualStudioVersion=10.0`

Comment: Are there any error messages? please share a simple demo via OneDrive.

Comment: Please provide the contents of `WebApp.pubxml` (sanitized if necessary).